# how to manufacture PTC ink

Tags: quantum-chemistry, nanotechnology, organosilicon-compounds, carbon-family

I am trying to create a PTC ink similar to Henkel ECI8120 , I researched PTC rubber and found that it was Polydimethylsiloxane (PDMS) loaded carbon nanoparticles, I was wondering if anyone here has some input on how to go about this.

I was thinking of dispersing carbon nanoparticles into the PDMS , but how do I get this to cure/solidify ?

I want to express that I am just asking for experimentation pointers/tips and not a complete solution.

Comment: I believe some formulations use a crystalline polymer such as polyethylene. I've heard pdms referenced on the internet and in wikipedia but never found it in a paper.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you have said what kind of polymer-based nanocomposites you would like to create. Yet, I found a good article for the fabrication of poly dimethylsiloxane/carbon nanofiber (CNF)-based nanocomposites. The schematic diagram of experimental procedure is illustrated in following figure (from the Ref. 1).

[image: PTC rubber]

The experimental section in Ref.1 describes the step-wise procedure for the fabrication. It also provides a useful few more references for polymer-based nanocomposite formulations. I also included another reference (Ref.2), which may be helpful to you.

---

**References:**

1. S. Chowdhury, M. Olima, Y. Liu, M. Saha, J. Bergman, T. Robison, Poly dimethylsiloxane/carbon nanofiber nanocomposites: fabrication and characterization of electrical and thermal properties, *International Journal of Smart and Nano Materials*, **2016**, *7(4)*, 236-247 (https://doi.org/10.1080/19475411.2016.1269027).
2. H. Azimi, F H. Tezel, J. Thibault, Effect of embedded activated carbon nanoparticles on the performance of polydimethylsiloxane (PDMS) membrane for pervaporation separation of butanol, *J. Chem. Technol. Biotechnol.*, **2017**, *92(12)*, 2901–2911 (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jctb.5306).

Comment: How is the PTC behavior accomplished?  I've heard of carbon black and pdms being used to make strain sensors but dont understand the PTC behavior or how to tune that.